# If $X,Y$ are positive exchangeable random variables, then $E\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)\geq 1$.

Tags: probability, statistics

I would like to show that if $X,Y$ are positive exchangeable random variables, then $E\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)\geq 1$. I have used several approaches, one is iterated condtioning, the other being the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but have not been able to find this bound. Does anyone have any ideas? I know also that a more general condition exists under which the inequality holds as well, which should involve finding concave functions and using Jensen's Inequality. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me what "exchangeable" really means. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent and with the same distribution? Do we know something else about their distributions?

Comment: Hi, exchangeable here doesn't mean independence but rather that the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is the same as the distribution of $(Y,X)$, that is, the distribution is the same under permututations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the expectation over the set $X\geqslant Y$ and its complement: 
$$\mathbb E\left[X/Y\right]=\mathbb E\left[X/Y\cdot\mathbf 1\{X\geqslant Y\}  \right]+\mathbb E\left[X/Y\cdot\mathbf 1\{X\lt Y\}  \right].$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are exchangeable, we have 
$$\mathbb E\left[X/Y\cdot\mathbf 1\{X\lt Y\}  \right]=\mathbb E\left[Y/X\cdot\mathbf 1\{Y\lt X\}  \right],$$
hence 
$$\mathbb E\left[X/Y\right]=\mathbb E\left[\left(X/Y+Y/X\right)\cdot\mathbf 1\{X\gt Y\}  \right]+\mathbb P\{X=Y\}.$$
For any positive real number $t$, we have $t+1/t\geqslant 2$, hence 
$$\mathbb E\left[X/Y\right]\geqslant 2\mathbb P\{Y\lt X\}+\mathbb P\{X=Y\}.$$
Using again exchangeability, we observe that the sum of probabilities is $1$, which gives the wanted inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! For this problem, it appears that I need to absolutely assume that $X,Y$ positive means that $Y > 0$ and $X > 0$? For the second to last equation, you had $\frac{Y}{X}$, which implies that $X >0$. Is it possible to do the problem but with  $Y > 0$ and $X \geq 0$? Thanks!

Comment: If $Y>0$ almost surely, then $X>0$ almost surely (since $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution).